# Install pgbench on non PostgreSql server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

I use pgbench tool on a CentOS 8 server without installed PostgreSQL.
In case Postgresql 10 install command is:

```
dnf install postgresql-contrib

pgbench --version
pgbench (PostgreSQL) 10.23
```

With PostgreSql 13 it does not work:

```
pgbench --version
-bash: pgbench: command not found
```

What package should I install for installing pgbanch tool?

Comment: What did you do? Just thinking about v13 wouldn't make the v10 disappear.  You must have done something

Comment: @jjanes I have installed few packages:  dnf install postgresql-contrib postgresql13  postgresql13-libs  
And bgbench tool is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgbench` is a client tool. Just install the `postgresql13` and the `postgresql13-libs` packages, and you are good.

Comment: I have installed the packages. Tool is not installed (. 
May be the pgbench tool was moved into an separate package?

Comment: Look around `/usr/pgsql-13/bin/pgbench` maybe the utility is installed but just not mentioned in $PATH

Comment: @Melkij thanks, it is the solution. Looks like an issue with PATH.